# Display WordPress posts with Featured Image on html

Tags: html, wordpress, posts

I'm building an app using Apache Cordova. I want to pull the posts from a WordPress site and display them on a html page.

Pull the last 10 posts.

Featured image as a thumbnail.

On click,display the post inside it without taking the user to the browser.

With pull to refresh.

With load more button at the bottom.

Please help me with your fullest support and the source code, I have not started this part yet.

Thanks

Comment: SO is not your personal app builder. If you have any kind of questions about a bug in the code, do ask and people will help. You cannot expect for people to code instead of you (I mean you can, but you usually need to pay them to do that ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything after loading the load.php file from wordpress. You can import , get , display any posts once you access the wordpress core functions by loading the load.php file